# What presentation/animation software will do this?

Tags: presentations, animation

I have an idea in my imagination for a slide, to be a part of a presentation I will be giving. I will decide on the presentation software to use (Open Office/Prezzie, Power Point, etc.) based on whether the software will be able to do the thing in my imagination. So, that's my question.

Is there a software that can make an animated slide like this.

It starts with some text written in blood, and then very slowly the blood starts dripping, overflowing the outlines of the text, and merging with other overflowing droplets thus distorting the written text and slowly merging into one pool of blood.

I would assume there is something that can do this because we see (and take for granted) a lot of things like this in the movies, esp. used for casting/credits at the beginning of the movie.

Comment: And most of it is done by hand.

Comment: Any 3D animation software (maya, lightwave, blender, etc) should be able to something like that.

Comment: Thank you, MaQleod. I am going to try some of the 3D animation software that are open sourced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in Flash. Though I would say it's likely overkill for a slideshow presentation.

If you turn it into an animated GIF though, you likely could embed it into a Powerpoint presentation.

Comment: Thanks, sidran. That is exactly what I had in mind. I'll make a flash thing and make a GIF out of it and paste it on my presentation slide. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation on this website to up vote your answer but I've marked it as the correct/best answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like to have a video and not a slidshow in the background, you could use something like the DVD chapters to jump to the next "slide".

So as MaQleod states, "Any 3D animation software".

But it also sounds like you are heading down the wrong track with to much focus on special effects and not enough focus on the content. Content is everything.

Comment: Thank you, Johan. I'll try some open source 3D animation software and see how it goes.